# problemas de compatibilidad

Tags: javascript, html, div, mediaqueries

Les vengo a presentar un problema de compatibilidad. La cuestión está en que creé un `div` a través de javascript y lo ingrese dentro de otro `div` que se encontraba directamente dentro de html y le di unas características particulares, el problema esta cuando el div creado a través de javasacript es cargado en distintas plataformas, iphone, chrome de pc..., pues cambia de tamaño, cosa que no pasa con el div creado desde html porque se encuentra en una grid,  cosa que no se si es posible hacer desde java. Ante este problema, se me había ocurrido usar las media queries, y es aquí donde se encuentra el segundo problema; parece que al crear la etiqueta desde java, css no la detecta, por lo que no le puedo cambiar las características al codigo en java. Intente con window.match.Media(), pero no me funciona, supongo que es porque el media querie no esta leyendo la etiqueta creada desde javascript. Aquí les dejo parte del código:

```
<body>
  <div class="principal">

    <div class="a">a</div>

    <div class="b" id="b">
      <span id="span1">
        <div class="b2">b2
        </div>
        <div class="b3">b3
        </div>
        <div class="b4">b4
        </div>
        <div class="b5">b5
        </div>
        <div class="b6">b6
        </div>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Codigo css:

```
@media (orientation:landscape){
    .div1{width:80%;}
  }
```

codigo javascript

```
let div1 = "";
function agregar() {
  div1 = document.createElement("div");
  div1.setAttribute(
    "style",
    "height:17%; width:95% ; font-size:20px; padding-left:15px; padding-top:10px; margin-top: 10px; margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px; border-radius: 10px; background-color:#283747 ; margin-top:10px; box-sizing: border-box;color:#FFF;"
  );
  span1.appendChild(div1);
}
var media = window.matchMedia("(orientation:landscape)");
if (media.matches) {
  console.log("prueba");
}
```

Básicamente pretendía que cuando estuviera en modo horizontal o superara cierto tamaño, las características de mi `div` creado desde javascript modificara sus valores, pero haciendo la prueba on el `console.log`, simplemente no funciona correcto, cuando el cel no esta en modo horizontal funciona, o simplemente no pasa nada.
Muchas gracias por sus servicios

Comment: Ninguna clase en tu html tiene el nombre `div1`. Entonces que se supone que va a cambiar?

Comment: Buenas. Veo que se me olvido parte del código Java .                                                                                          let div1="";
function agregar(){
 div1=document.createElement("div");    div1.setAttribute("style", "height:17%; width:95% ; font-size:20px; padding-left:15px; padding-top:10px; margin-top: 10px; margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px; border-radius: 10px; background-color:#283747 ; margin-top:10px; box-sizing: border-box;color:#FFF;");
   span1.appendChild(div1); El span contiene todos los div en java

Answer (score 0):

Funciona para mi cuando escribo:

```
@media (orientation: landscape) {
  .div1 {
    width: 80% !important;
  }
}
```

Tu código tampoco incluía `div1.className = "div1";`